# How do I close the sidebar in Firefox's developer tools?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I've opened Firefox developer tools, the Network tab, and I've clicked on one of the resources being. This opens a sidebar. How do I close the sidebar again? I can't work it out.

[image]

Comment: Very top right button…?

Comment: @deceze Thank you, that's exactly it! (Although you can't see it in the screenshot because the window is too small.)

Comment: I actually do mean the top right button visible in the screenshot. The square-with-a-vertical-line-two-thirds-over.

Comment: @deceze That button docks the window to the side of the main Firefox window, it doesn't close the sidebar with "Headers", "Cookies", "Params", "Response" tabs.

Comment: I see, was just a best guess… :o)

Answer (score 3):

There is a button, but it only appears if the window holding the developer tools is large enough.

[image: Screenshot]